# Evaluation of custom If representation terminates if a guard to a statement is false

Tags: parsing, if-statement, haskell, eval

If-statements in my language should be in the following form:

```
if ((4 div 2) = 2)-> print(1)
[] ((4 div 2) > 1)-> print(2)
[] ((4 div 2) > 2)-> print(3)
fi
```

The output to this should be one and two printed to the console however if I were to switch the positions of the middle and last statement, only the first statement would be evaluated and then the program would terminate. It seems that the behaviour that is exhibited is that the evaluation of the if-statements is predicated upon the value of the guard such that if 1..n guards are true and if the n+1 guard is false, then the "falseness" breaks the evaluation.

I think I narrowed down the issue to how an if-statement is individually evaluated.

```
evalStatement_ env (If cond expr) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                                     HBool False -> return ()
                                                                     HBool True  -> traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) expr
```

If a statement whose guard (`cond`) is evaluated to false then the path that's taken is `return ()`. It seems that if this is taken then the program stops because when all guards are true then the statements can be executed. But in my evaluation of basic datatypes, I also have `return ()` :

```
evalStatement_ env (Eval val) = do
    result <- evalVal env val
    return ()
```

This function takes a `HVal` and evaluates it and returns `()` but given the behaviour of what is occurring with if-statements, this has left me really confused because in this case, the program doesn't stop.

The other possible issue could be down to my representation of if-statements.

```
data HVal
  = HInteger Integer
  | HBool    Bool
  | HString  String
  | HList    [HVal]
  | Length   HVal
  | Arith    HVal Op HVal
  | Assign   String HVal
    deriving (Eq, Read)


data HStatement
  =  Eval   HVal
  |  Print  HVal
  |  Do     HVal [HStatement]
  |  Selection [HStatement]
  |  If     HVal [HStatement]
  |  Skip   String
    deriving (Eq, Read)
```

An if-statement is built up from a single `HVal`, the guard/cond and a list of `HStatements` which carry out what is to be evaluated if the guard is true. `Selection` however is what actually handles the work. It is supposed to be representative of multiple if-statements hence the list.

```
parseIf :: Parser HStatement
parseIf = do
        string "if" <|> string "[]"
        spaces
        string "("
        cond  <- parseVals
        string ")->"
        spaces
        expr  <- many1 (try (parseSkip) <|> try (parseDo <* spaces) <|> try (parsePrint) <|> try (parseEvalHVal))
        return $ If cond expr


parseSelection :: Parser HStatement
parseSelection = liftM Selection $ (many1 parseIf)
```

So when I go to evaluate `Selection`, what's supposed to occur is that the `evalStatement_ env` function is applied to each entry within the list which in turn allows for the entirety of the list to be evaluated but clearly that's not the case! When I went to print out what was actually "in' the `Selection` in the following program, only the first statement was found within the block:

```
if ((4 div 2) = 2)-> print(1)
[] ((4 div 2) < 1)-> print(2)
[] ((4 div 2) > 1)-> print(3)
fi

./Main if.oli
[Print (1 )
[]

]
1
```

This leads me to believe it's either a parsing error or there's something to do with `return ()` but I genuinely don't know how to proceed.

```
----- EVAULATION FUNCTIONS -----
evalStatement_ :: Env -> HStatement -> IOThrowsError ()
evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                                 HBool False -> return ()
                                                                 HBool True  -> do
                                                                         traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) expr
                                                                         evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr)

evalStatement_ env (Skip skip) = return ()
evalStatement_ env (Print (HString val)) = getVar env val >>= \x -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ show x
evalStatement_ env (Print val) = evalVal env val >>= \x -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ show x
evalStatement_ env (Eval val) = do
    result <- evalVal env val
    return ()
evalStatement_ env (If cond expr) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                                     HBool False -> return ()
                                                                     HBool True  -> traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) expr
evalStatement_ env (Selection selection) = do
        traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) selection
```

Comment: I find it suspicious that the string `fi` does not appear anywhere in the parsing code you've shown us. Anyway, the first step to debugging this is definitely minimize, minimize, minimize.

Comment: Well that is a different problem that I'm still working on. If I were to include `<* string ''fi"` to the right of `parseSelection`, the program doesn't work but only works once its removed

Comment: How do you know it is a different problem? These categorical statements about things you don't understand so much that you are asking other people to help you always puzzle me. Either you understand the problem -- in which case, great! you can fix it -- or you don't, in which case anything you believe about it is suspect and should be internally treated with the greatest skepticism.

Comment: Right guess I'll delete the question and see what I can come up with in the meantime....

Comment: I think your AST and parser is "wrong", in the sense that you are parsing your code using an inconvenient representation. I would expect the `If` constructor to be defined as `If [(HVal, [HStatement]]` in order to comprise all the branches. Instead, you only parse one, so later on you struggle in giving a semantics to a single branch. The problem would not exist if you represented the if construct by taking all the branches in one gulp, parsing it accordingly.

Comment: @chi That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!!

Comment: @chi I switched my representation to your suggestion and a few others things around and everything works perfectly now! Thanks!